# What are the command line options for the PC/Mac version of Braid?

Tags: braid

The launcher for the PC/Mac version of Braid has a box for command line options, but I've not been able to find a list of the available options. Can anyone provide a list of them, along with what they do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a list of the command line options I could find.

Format:
"(option) (parameter)" (Description)

## Language

"-language X" (Change the game language, can be one of any of the following: English, German, French, Italian, Spanish, Japanese, Korean, Chinese)

## Graphic Options

"-windowed" (Run the game in windowed mode, as opposed to full-screen)

"-vsync" (Turn on [Vsync](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/V/Vsync.html))
"-no_vsync" (Force no [Vsync](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/V/Vsync.html))

"-half" (Not sure on this, I assume it graphically scales down the rendering/resolution/etc by half)
"-no_post" (No post-processing effects)

"-60fps" (Force the game to run at 60fps)
"-30fps" (Force the game to run at 30fps)
"-20fps" (Force the game to run at 20fps)
"-15fps" (Force the game to run at 15fps)

"-width X" (Specify the width resolution of the game)
"-height Y" (Specify the height resolution of the game)

## Sound

"-no_music" (Turn off all music)

### Level Creator/Editor

There are some other options which relate to creating content for Braid that you can read about [here](http://braid-game.com/news/?p=576) on the developer's blog.