# Why are my Sprites Flickering in Braid?

Tags: technical-issues, braid

While playing Braid, I constantly see sprites flickering and disappearing through the whole game. I have searched a lot but no one seems to have the same problem on PC or Console.

here are some example screenshots:
[image: weird artifacts]
[image: more weird stuff]
[image: disappearing stuff]

here is the [full album of woe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGJRb.jpg)

I bought Braid as part of Humble Bundle 3 and activated it on Steam.

It is running on XP Professional with 2.00 GHz processor and 1.37 GB of RAM video card Nvidia GeForce 6100

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't have a specific answer for you, but you should try manually updating Direct X and your graphics card drivers. If that doesn't help, updating your .net, c++, and visual basic redistributable packages might do the trick (I'm not sure which, if any, of those three Braid uses).

Comment: @Fambida I don't have a .net framework installed, and it seems that Braid's programmer [might use C++](http://braid-game.com/news/2009/09/now-hiring-a-programmer/). Sorry i'm dumb how would you manually update DirectX a redistributable package?

Comment: To update Direct X for XP use [this](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=35). To update your c++ use [this](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5555)

Comment: Steam should actually take care of all required DirectX, .net, vlc and whatnot files. [Too much](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30393/how-can-steam-be-prevented-from-downloading-a-billion-copies-of-directx) sometimes...

Comment: I only play Braid through Steam which i keep up to date. does that mean i don't need to manually update my redistributable packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had that flickering, too. Turning VSync off did the trick for me: In Steam, right click Braid, choose properties, then Set Launch Options... and enter `-no_vsync` there. You can also try `-windowed` or `-30fps`. There's a [list of Braid's command line switches](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14492/what-are-the-command-line-options-for-the-pc-mac-version-of-braid) with which you could further play around.

If you're not running Braid via Steam, first, as Fambida suggested, make sure you got the required DirectX files etc. Then right click your Braid shortcut, choose properties and append `-no_vsync` after Braid.exe (if there are quotes, *after* these).

Comment: '-no_vsync' had no apparent effect for me. Neither did '-30fps', '-half', '-windowed' or '-no_post', sorry.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Is this the only game where you are experiencing graphic glitches? Did you, as Fambida and TrewTzu suggested, update your graphics card drivers? That's the only thing Steam does _not_ automatically install, though it should give you a warning if it detects outdated drivers (unless one ticks the don't remind me again box)

Comment: No, i have not updated my graphics card driver, but this is the only game that has had problems. how would i manually update my Nvida graphics card drivers?

Comment: @RedriderX: I think Steam has a `Check for graphics driver updates...` item in its main menu taking you to http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx. Also, is it a Desktop PC or a notebook?

Comment: I updated my graphics card drivers and all the flickering went away, thanks .

Answer (score 1):

All I can suggest is updating your Graphics card and C++ redistributable package like Fambida suggested above, and then try running as administrator.

Comment: I have added my video card onto the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had the whole game screen flashing in fullscreen mode.  I fixed it by right click>properties braid in steam, and "set startup options to -no_vsync
this fixed it for me.